# Можно ли восстановить windows если удалены все файлы?

Tags: windows-10, recovery

Я поставил Ubuntu и... очистил диск с виндой. Можно ли КАК-ТО восстановить виндовс или тогда при переустановке винды и заход в аккаунт Microsoft вернётся ли ключ активации?

Comment: Теоретически, если ты был залогинен в винду под ms-аккаунтом, то после переустановки при входе под ним же лицензия восстановится. А может и без него восстановится, т. к. комп тот же, хотя я не уверен. А с диска стоит сделать образ на случай, если не получится. Ну или на случай, если там файлы были нужные.

Comment: Если вы перезаписали диск убунтой, то восстановить старое содержимое уже не получится. Разве что частично оставшиеся ошмётки файлов пытаться выгребать...